# DataFrame: Convert the columns in a df to list of row in Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like below

```
id     name     value1   value2    value3     Type
=======================================================
 1     AAA       1.0       1.5       1.8      NEW
 2     BBB       2.0       2.3       2.5      NEW
 3     CCC       3.0       3.6       3.7      NEW
```

I have convert the above df into something like below so that i can join it to another df based on name (which will be unique in my case)

```
Type        AAA                     BBB                 CCC
================================================================
NEW    [1.0, 1.5, 1.8]       [2.0, 2.3, 2.5]      [3.0, 3.6, 3.7]
```

Is there any way to achieve this instead of having too many looping statements.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide the work you've tried so far. You had a nearly identical question answered just a few minutes ago that deals with the list making part. Is this just a swapping rows and columns question? Maybe transpose? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html

Comment: That seems like an odd transformation to then do for a join. Wouldn't you want to make "name" an index and do the join that way? And why do you need to make a list to do the join?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution, which first adds column `value` containing the list and then uses [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
(df.assign(value=df.loc[:, 'value1':'value3'].apply(list, axis=1))
 .pivot(index='Type', columns='name', values='value')
 .rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
  Type              AAA              BBB              CCC
0  NEW  [1.0, 1.5, 1.8]  [2.0, 2.3, 2.5]  [3.0, 3.6, 3.7]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
(df.melt(['id', 'name', 'Type'])
   .pivot_table(index='Type', columns='name',
                values='value', aggfunc=list)
   .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
  Type              AAA              BBB              CCC
0  NEW  [1.0, 1.5, 1.8]  [2.0, 2.3, 2.5]  [3.0, 3.6, 3.7]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`groupby_agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
>>> (df.melt(['id', 'name', 'Type'])
       .groupby(['name', 'Type'])['value']
       .agg(list).unstack('name')
       .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None))

  Type              AAA              BBB              CCC
0  NEW  [1.0, 1.5, 1.8]  [2.0, 2.3, 2.5]  [3.0, 3.6, 3.7]
```

*Edit: this is almost equivalent to @mozway's answer.*

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to handle the Type column for instances where it is not "NEW"?

Ignoring that for now. You can do something like the following...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['AAA','BBB','CCC'],'value1':[1,2,3],'value2':[4,5,6]})
columns = df.name.values
values = df[[i for i in df.columns if 'value' in i]].values
df = pd.Series(dict(zip(columns, values))).to_frame().T
```